# How to add file element in zend form?

Tags: php, zend-framework, file-upload, zend-form

I am creating forms like this:

**UploadFiale.php**

```
<?php 

class Form_UploadFile extends Zend_Form {

    public function __construct( $options = null ) {

        parent::__construct( $options );    
        $this->setMethod('post');
        $elements = array();

        // photo
        $element = new Zend_Form_Element_File('photo');
        $element->setLabel('Photo');
        $element->addValidator('Count', false, 1);
        $element->addValidator('Size', false, 102400);
        $element->addValidator('Extension', false, 'jpg,png,gif');
        $elements[] = $element;

        // submit button      
        $element = $this->CreateElement('submit', 'submit');
        $element->setLabel('Save');
        $elements[] = $element;

        $this->addElements( $elements );
        $this->setElementDecorators( array( 'ViewHelper' ) );          
        $this->setDecorators( array( array( 'ViewScript', array( 'viewScript' => 'uploadfile-form.phtml' ) ) ) );

    } // end construct       
} // end class
?>
```

**uploadfile-form.phtml**

```
<form action=<?= $this->element->getAction() ?> method=<?= $this->element->getMethod() ?> id='AddNotificationForm' enctype='multipart/form-data' class='AjaxForm'>    
<table border='0'>   
    <tr>
        <td><label><?= $this->element->photo->getLabel() ?></label></td>
        <td><?= $this->element->photo; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><?= $this->element->submit; ?></td>
    </tr>       
</table>    
</form>
```

When I initialize form class and render it in view then **I am getting following error:**

> Warning: No file decorator found... unable to render file element in
>   /project_folder/library/Zend/Form/Element.php on line 2041

Same structure is working with other form elements but not working with **file** element. Can someone tell me that what is wrong here ?

Thanks

Comment: I tried this 
`$element->setDecorators(array(
    array('File'),
    array('Errors')
));` with file element but still getting same warning. source: http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFFAQ/Forms

Comment: It looks like this type of error:  http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=69&t=1701

Comment: In that case your answer could be this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143462/how-do-i-use-viewscripts-on-zend-form-file-elements

Answer (score 2):

Zend_Form_Element_File is special in a way that it does not work without "File" Decorator either you add it specifically or remove

```
$this->setElementDecorators( array( 'ViewHelper' ) );
```