# Zend Form reCaptcha ViewScript Decorator

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element, zend-decorators

I want to use a view script decorator on a reCAPTCHA field.  If I use my standard view script as a decorator, the output is a text input field.  Here is my standard form field view script:

```
<?php
$class = 'field ' . strtolower(end(explode('_',$this->element->getType())));
if ($this->element->isRequired()) {
    $class .= ' required';
}
if ($this->element->hasErrors()) {
    $class .= ' errors';
}
if (0 < strlen($this->element->class)) {
    $class .= ' ' . $this->element->class;
}
?>
<div class="<?php echo $class; ?>" id="field_<?php echo $this->element->getId(); ?>">
    <?php if (0 < strlen($this->element->getLabel())) {
        $labelAttribs = $this->element->getAttribs();
        if ($this->element->isRequired()) {
            $labelAttribs['escape'] = false;
            $this->element->setLabel($this->element->getLabel() . ' <span class="screenreader">required</span>');
        }
        echo $this->formLabel($this->element->getFullyQualifiedName(), $this->element->getLabel(), $labelAttribs);
    } ?>
    <span class="value"><?php echo $this->{$this->element->helper}(
        $this->element->getFullyQualifiedName(),
        $this->element->getValue(),
        $this->element->getAttribs()
    ); ?></span>
    <?php if (0 < strlen($this->element->getDescription())): ?>
        <div class="hint"><?php echo $this->element->getDescription(); ?></div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($this->element->hasErrors()): ?>
        <?php echo $this->formErrors($this->element->getMessages()); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

I'm fairly certain that the part I need to change is this:

```
<span class="value"><?php echo $this->{$this->element->helper}(
    $this->element->getFullyQualifiedName(),
    $this->element->getValue(),
    $this->element->getAttribs()
); ?></span>
```

...but I don't know what to change it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, this can be accomplished the same way as the solution to my question: [How do I use ViewScripts on Zend_Form File Elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143462/how-do-i-use-viewscripts-on-zend-form-file-elements)

Form Element:

```
$this->addElement('captcha', 'captcha', array(
    'disableLoadDefaultDecorators' => true,
    'decorators' => array(
        'Captcha_ReCaptcha',
        array(
            'ViewScript',
            array(
                'viewScript' => '_form/recaptcha.phtml',
                'placement' => false,
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'label' => 'Verification',
    'required' => true,
    'captcha' => array(
        'pubkey' => $options['recaptcha']['pubkey'],
        'privkey' => $options['recaptcha']['privkey'],
        'theme' => 'white',
        'captcha' => 'reCaptcha',
    ),
));
```

In the view script, output the reCAPTCHA content like this:

```
<?php echo $this->content; ?>
```